# Is there a way of getting a super magical chest or a legendary in Clash Royale?

Tags: clash-royale

I am in Royale Arena and I still can't obtain a legendary card. All I got is this hut spawner and second of all, I got too many epics and people keep beating me with those legendary cards.

Comment: One [source](http://clashroyalearena.com/guides/get-legendary-cards) suggests: "I’ve done some research by compiling data from over 100 super magical chest openings from players in Arena 9 from the recent update, and I’ve found that the chances of obtaining 1 of the 5 Legendary cards from a single **Super Magical Chest is about 40%**"  When you say you want to know the percentage, do you mean across all possible ways to obtain one?

Comment: You've accepted an answer, and let a bounty time out on a different answer. Now you've put up another bounty with a nonsensical description. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I am not understanding why an open bounty was offered, then applied to an old answer that was not updated despite new answers (I am not trying to farm reputation; I just don't understand your motive behind offering this bounty, especially after there has been an accepted answer, and the answer that you gave the bounty to [twice!] is not your accepted answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only a few ways to get them, but it's possible. The following are based on being in Arena 9:

1. Opening Super Magical Chests **-** Super magical chests are the highest quality chest in Clash Royale. They can be obtained by buying them for 4600 gems in the store, or getting a very lucky drop at the end of a battle.
2. Buying them from the shop - While rare, they will sometimes appear in the shop and costs 40,000 gold. This is actually a much better deal than the Super Magical chests because 40,000 gold is about 2,000 gems.

Other than that, there's not much to do. There is a better chance to get a Super magical chest drop as the higher your rank is, so just keep trying to climb and refine your deck to the meta.

Comment: You do know the OP mentioned the newer Legendary ***chest*** right?

Comment: Nope, I am trying to get a legendary card by luck or probably for that free to play player such as myself trying to get a legendary card although I am not that rich.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to obtain Super Magical Chest and legendaries. However, I'm assuming that you do not wish to pay a lot of money on this game, so I didn't include the option of purchasing Legendary King's chest. However, Legendary chests are a feasible option, so that's included below.

- Attempt to obtain the chest from battle. 
  *You are guaranteed a Super Magical Chest, Legendary chest, and Epic chest every 500 chests. That means you have a 0.40% chance of obtaining a super magical/legendary chest from winning a battle. If you want to know EXACTLY when your Super Magical and/or Legendary chest will arrive, try royaleapi.com. **Conditions: Arena 2 or above to get a Super Magical chest, Arena 7 or above for legendary chest***
- Purchase legendaries from the shop with gold 
  *Occasionally, legendaries will appear in the shop, purchasable for 40 000 gold. This method is best if you want a specific legendary. **Conditions: Arena 10 or above for legendaries to appear in the shop***
- Wait for the Legendary Chest Offer to appear in the shop 
  *Occasionally, a Legendary chest will appear in the shop and can be purchased for 500 gems. This chest unlocks immediately and is limited to 1 per offer. (The offer will appear multiple times, however, usually every few weeks.) This chest guarantees 1 Legendary from **any** arena, but it's random, so it's best if you don't care what legendary you get. **Conditions: Arena 4 or above (unverified) to receive chest offer***
- Try and get it from regular chests. **Conditions: Arena 4 or above**
  *Check out the chances of getting a legendary of any chest here: https://pixelcrux.com/Clash_Royale/Card_Chance/Calculator*
- Obtain Super Magical, Legendary, and Legendary King's chests from Quests 
  *With the latest update (10/9/2017), chests are now obtainable as a Points reward for completing quests, and can reward ANY chest obtainable from battle (except Silver), as shown in the Quests screen.*

Sources:

- http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Chests - card rarity, chest cycles, arena requirements for special chests
- I purchased 2 legendaries with gold.
- Personal experience - purchased legendary chest on Arenas 6, 8, 10, 11

Comment: Thanks! Even though I am in arena 10, this suggestion was helpful.

Comment: +1, this is better than the accepted answer IMO

Answer (score 3):

Since you have put up a bounty and indicated that you are looking for the exact percentages of getting a legendary card drop, the formula for this can be found [here](http://clashroyalearena.com/guides/card-drop-rates):

> % Chance = ((Cards in Chest * # Legendary)/# Commons)/Legendary Factor

On the page, there are more detailed breakdowns of the legendary chance based on Arena level and type of chest, which I believe is what you are looking for.

Comment: Nice! I understand the odds!

Answer (score 2):

While Legendary cards are technically obtainable from any chest beside the epic chest, they are fairly rare. Super magical chests, which drop randomly in 500 chests won from battle, have about a 50% legendary drop rate. The legendary chest, which has the same odds of a super magic chest from dropping, contains one guaranteed legendary. And, legendary cards appear in the shop if you are in legendary arena every so often. Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKJL76hyonw) video from Orange Juice.

Comment: Takes about an entire year and it used to be 1/1000 and now it's 1/500

Answer (score 1):

I only have the log, the lava hound and the inferno dragon. I just got the inferno dragon from a free chest which made me flip out. I got the lava hound from buying the Royal Arena bundle and I spent the ready of those gems on the legendary chest that appeared the next day. You can also get them from spending gems when they are released in the shop.

Answer (score 1):

My first Legendary was EWiz from a clan chest at arena 7 (about 7% chance at 10/10) Next week, I got Lava Hound from another 10/10 clan chest. Join a clan with good reputation and hope for the best. Also, You always pull a Legendary chest as first chest in third cycle. I wish you good luck.

Comment: That's cool! Legendaries are common for me because of Hog Mountain.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get any legendary , but I was still in jungle Adena. But one day i opened the clan chest I got log and next week got princess, and next week got best legendary ewiz

Comment: Cool! Even though I have too many legendaries, I am just testing them.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a legendary or magical chest depends on chest cycle . legendary chests comes in around once in 500 cheat once you  have unlocked legendary cards after reaching certain arena I only got one legendary chest and got inferno dragon  and got 3 legendary cards from other chests .I think there are some apps that keep track of this cycle